# android-graphview library - Chart not showing all x axis values

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I'm trying to figure out why the graph is not showing all x-axis values, I'm trying to get it to show 1,2,3,.... but it goes 2...4...6.

Any idea on how to force the graph to show all values?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will help:

```
yourGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(numberOfBars);
```